LCD PCB component identification, SOT-23-5, "DK-NON"
I have a question about an SMD component that blew up on my microscope's LCD PCB. It has 5 pins (2 on one side and 3 on the other), the lettering on the back says DK-NON.

enter image description here
enter image description here
[![enter image description here][3]][3]


If you get a good answer, thank them by accepting the answer and (when you have enough rep) upvoting.

SMD codes are short and ambiguous, and context is often helpful for identification -- could you show a wider view of what's around the component, what it connects to, perhaps some measurements if it's in semi-working order? || What are its dimensions? (I've added the likely package type to the title, but it helps to be sure.)

Thank you for the response, it is greatly appreciated. I will try to get a pic of the whole PCB. It isnt in any working order at the moment so I cant get any measurements from it.

The ultimate SMD marking codes database page for marking codes starting with DK shows several results for DK-. The only result for a SOT-23-5 package is the Richtek Technology RT9193-30PB which is described as a "Linear voltage regulator IC LDO, 3.0V±1%, 300mA, +CE"
The Richtek product page is RT9193 300mA, Ultra-Low Noise, Ultra-Fast CMOS LDO Regulator and there is the datasheet. Unfortunately the datasheet just contains the following for Marking Information:

For marking information, contact our sales representative
directly or through a Richtek distributor located in your
area.

On a different site found Richtek MARKING INFORMATION. In that document the only value of DK- as a Product Code in a SOT-23-5 package is for RT9193-30PB, which matches the information from the ultimate SMD marking codes database page.
It is likely that the NON suffix on the device is some sort of manufacturing lot information. However, have been unable to find any Richtek information to confirm the marking code format nor any pictures of an actual  RT9193-30PB device.
The RT9193-30PB datasheet has the following Pin Configurartion:

And typical application circuit:

The description of the BP pin contains:

Reference Noise Bypass. This pin cannot be floating. Recommended to connect a 22nF or larger ceramic capacitor between the BP and GND pins.

If you take a picture of the surrounding components of the SMD component, and see if can trace some of the connections, that would help to confirm if the SMD component matches the usage for a RT9193-30PB.

Wow, that is a good bit of info! Thank you very much. The really unfortunate part is, when the board burnt it also took some of the tracing with it. I think I can repair or at the very least, jumper it but the pics I will upload may not be much help. Ill give it a shot though.
